# Select condition within a hash column using Doctrine mongoDB ODM query builder

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I have the following structure within a mongoDB collection:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5301d337fa46346a048b4567"),
        "delivery_attempts" : {
                "0" : {
                        "live_feed_id" : 107,
                        "remaining_attempts" : 2,
                        "delivered" : false,
                        "determined_status" : null,
                        "date" : 1392628536
                }
        }
}
```

// > db.lead.find({}, {delivery_attempts:1}).pretty();

I'm trying to select any data from that collection where remaining_attempts are greater than 0 and a live_feed_id is equal to 107. Note that the "delivery_attempts" field is of a type hash.

I've tried using an addAnd within an elemMatch (not sure if this is the correct way to achieve this).

```
    $qb = $this->dm->createQueryBuilder($this->getDocumentName());

    $qb->expr()->field('delivery_attempts')
        ->elemMatch(
            $qb->expr()
                ->field('remaining_attempts')->gt(0)
                ->addAnd($qb->expr()->field('live_feed_id')->equals(107))
    );
```

I do appear to be getting the record detailed above. However, changing the greater than 
test to 3

```
->field('remaining_attempts')->gt(3)
```

still returns the record (which is incorrect). Is there a way to achieve this?

---

**EDIT:** I've updated the delivery_attempts field type from a "Hash" to a "Collection". This shows the data being stored as an array rather than an object:

```
    "delivery_attempts" : [
            {
                    "live_feed_id" : 107,
                    "remaining_attempts" : 2,
                    "delivered" : false,
                    "determined_status" : null,
                    "date" : 1392648433
            }
    ]
```

However, the original issue still applies.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you mean by "Note that the "delivery_attempts" field is of a type hash"? I've never heard of hash type, only hash indexes, a reference to the documentation is highly appreciated, thank you! EDITED COMMENT: Oh, never mind, looks like it a type in doctrine not in mongodb itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dot notation to reference elements within a collection.

```
    $qb->field('delivery_attempts.remaining_attempts')->gt(0)
       ->field('delivery_attempts.live_feed_id')->equals(107);
```

Comment: oh, sorry, didn't noticed your answer, looks like you solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me if I run the query on mongo.

```
db.testQ.find({"delivery_attempts.remaining_attempts" : {"$gt" : 0}, "delivery_attempts.live_feed_id" : 107}).pretty()
```

so it seems something wrong with your PHP query, I suggest running profiler to see which query is actually run against mongo

```
db.setProfilingLevel(2)
```

This will log all operation since you enable profiling. Then you can query the log to see which the actual queries

```
db.system.profile.find().pretty()
```

This might help you to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your solved your first problem, which was using the `Hash` type mapping (instead for storing BSON objects, or associative arrays in PHP) instead of the `Collection` mapping (intended for real arrays); however, the query criteria in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21832394/162228) you submitted still seems incorrect.

```
$qb->field('delivery_attempts.remaining_attempts')->gt(0)
   ->field('delivery_attempts.live_feed_id')->equals(107);
```

You said in your original question:

> I'm trying to select any data from that collection where remaining_attempts are greater than 0 and a live_feed_id is equal to 107.

I assume you'd like that criteria to be satisfied by a single element within the `delivery_attempts` array. If that's correct, the criteria you specified above may match more than you expect, since `delivery_attempts.remaining_attempts` can refer to *any* element in the array, as can the `live_feed_id` criteria. You'll want to use [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to restrict the field criteria to a single array element.

I see you were using `elemMatch()` in your original question, but the syntax looked a bit odd. There should be no need to use `addAnd()` (i.e. an `$and` operator) unless you were attempting to apply two query operators to the same field name. Simply add extra `field()` calls to the same query expression you're using for the `elemMatch()` method. One example of this from ODM's test suite is [`QueryTest::testElemMatch()`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/1d125bfa2b47abe70cfecdbce1a1ea50eaa8d819/tests/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Tests/QueryTest.php#L135). You can also use the `debug()` method on the query to see the raw MongoDB query object created by ODM's query builder.